# Creating s simple client/server UDP example in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, networking, udp, client-server

I'm trying to make a simple UDP client server example in PHP but I face an error.

This is the client :

```
$fp = stream_socket_client("udp://192.168.0.12:12478", $errno, $errstr);

if ($fp)
{
        fwrite($fp, "TEST 1 TEST 2 TEST 3");
        $buf = fgets($fp);
        var_dump($buf);
        fclose($fp);
}
```

This is the server :

```
$socket = stream_socket_server("udp://192.168.0.12:12478", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND);
if ($socket)
{
  while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
    fwrite($conn, date("D M j H:i:s Y\r\n"));
    fclose($conn);
  }
  fclose($socket);
}
```

All executions end with :

```
Warning: stream_socket_accept(): accept failed: Operation not supported
```

Basically, this is the example given in all PHP documentations but I can't figure what is wrong in it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the warning on the very same page

> *Warning* 
>   This function should not be used with UDP server sockets. Instead,
>   use stream_socket_recvfrom() and
>   stream_socket_sendto().

Comment: Good. With "stream_socket_recvfrom()" everything is OK !

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation](http://www.sockets.com/err_lst1.htm#WSAEOPNOTSUPP): "you cannot make a silk piurse from a sow's ear"

stream_socket_connect is intended for STREAMS, not datagram packets.  recvfrom would be more likely to work in this scenario.